# What are the locations of all the security chests on Rishi?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

What are the locations of all the security chests on Rishi?

I know there is a chest under a shipwreck, but I don't know the others.

Comment: Heads up that the chests have be nerfed pretty hard as of this morning's patch (3.0.0a).  Credit amounts are a bit lower and the respawn time is quite high, so it's not worth farming them instead of dailies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the ones I've found so far (none on Sky Ridge Island yet):

## [Horizon Island](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8lat.jpg)

- [(-909, 149, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imrmb.jpg) — out in open water just offshore
- [(-828, -21, 18)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV8EV.jpg) — on a platform near a Nova Blade ship
- [(-388, 85, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn2gr.jpg) — tucked between rocks against some ship wreckage
- [(-264, 35, -2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnwSv.jpg) — between two islands
- [(48, 244, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hZ2P.jpg) — in a narrow canyon
- [(106, 193, -2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMYRu.jpg) — under some wreckage
- [(316, 252, -2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFmBT.jpg) — in the water near some wreckage

## [Raider's Cove Slums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4AN3.jpg)

Outer edges in the water.

- [(835, 332, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg5nl.jpg)
- [(1232, 351, -2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qroNu.jpg)

## [East Beach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2JKT.jpg)

- [(1237, 91, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLuEB.jpg) — near wreckage

## [Slave Island](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF2ye.jpg)

All near wreckage.

- [(3115, -1623, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoYtI.jpg)
- [(3003, -1628, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZRT0.jpg)
- [(2817, -2117, -3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvd2Q.jpg)